# Could not connect to imap.gmail.com even providing correct credentials and appropirate settings

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I configured gmail to get connected to imap.gmail.com in my web application. To do so I enable imap access and allowed to access the less secure app. But still I could not get connected to gmail imap.

first I tried -

```
imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX','gmailaccount','password') 
        or die('Cannot connect to Webmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

This gives error of **Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3** and I tried with `novalidate-cert` option which comes with vulnerability. And the code is -

```
imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX','gmailaccount','password') 
        or die('Cannot connect to Webmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

This gives error - **Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)** even username and password are correct.

Actually, I want to connect with providing certificate. I googled - "How to issue certificate for GMAIL IMAP connection", but nothing useful there. What's wrong with this code while it's perfectly working with other web account. What should I do make it workable.

Comment: Just to make sure, you've enabled IMAP, right? It's in settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP in gmail.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld thats done 100% sure